# How can I tell water pressure is too high for the washing machine?

Tags: washing-machine, water-pressure

The technician installing our washing machine said that the water pressure in the pipe to which our washing machine is connected is too high, and that it will break if we use it this way.  The manual says that it should be between 100 and 1000 kPa and that if it's higher [we should have a valve installed](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/15700/20130).  I have contacted the apartment building management company, so it is theoretically possible that they will do something within the next six to eight weeks, but they probably won't tell me when they have.  How can I tell if/that the water pressure is too high (and thus, later tell when it no longer is)?

I have tried to take a photo of water flowing into an empty washing compartment, but it's difficult:
[image: Water]

Comment: A Photo of the water can not tell us anything. How did the technician know that the water pressure is "to high" ? What technician?

Comment: Note that water pressure that high isn't good for the rest of your plumbing system either. Residential pipes are only designed to withstand a certain water pressure.

Comment: That pressure range seems very high.  That could be correct, but I would double check that.  Also and incoming water pressure of over 1000kPa (145 PSI) is _extremely_ high based on what I'm used to seeing.

Comment: @JPhi1618 we have 9 bar regulated down to 3.5bar - good showers though... A good jet is always better than a dribble..

Comment: @SolarMike if that step down is common, I guess it's possible that a regulator has failed in this apartment?  Anything with an electric valve (dishwasher, ice maker) would have issues with that pressure right?  Or is 9-10 bar more common than I think?

Comment: @Alaskaman The technician from the company installing the washing machine switched on the machine, looked at the water, and said there was too much water.

Comment: @JPhi1618 That's what it says in the manual.  It's possible that the technician is wrong and that the water pressure is fine.

Comment: @JPhi1618 well having a regulator right after the main isolation valve is standard here in Switzerland.

Comment: @gerrit Technicians are not usually installers. Did he/she call themselves a technician ? *Do they work for the manufacturer or authorized repair shop, or just the store where you purchased the machine*.  ** It's possible that the technician is wrong and that the water pressure is fine**   yes, yes it is.  looking is not a accurate  assessment.

Comment: @Alaskaman Two people came to deliver and connect the washing machine.  I don't know what they call themselves.  I call them technicians because their job is technical.

Answer (score 4):

Water pressure gauges that connect to garden hose fittings are common at home stores in the US.  I assume you are from elsewhere because of the units you used for pressure, but, for instance, at Home Depot the gauges are found in the lawn sprinkler area because water pressure is an important consideration for the design of a sprinkler system.

[image]

You may have to look around at stores that sell irrigation or general plumbing supplies to find one.  For an online search "water hose pressure gauge" should give plenty of results.  Of course I'm also assuming that your washing machine uses the same fittings as a garden hose, so make sure you get the right connector (again, standard in the US).